# How can I do glass with a gradient?

Tags: materials, color

[image]
How can I obtain similar glass color, half is black and half is a little white

Comment: Hi, welcome to Blender.SE. This post would be improved by adding screenshots of your model, your current shader, your lighting setup, a description of what you tried and what failed and your **render engine**.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most basic solution is to plug a *Gradient Texture* node into a *ColorRamp* with your 2 colors, then plug it in the *Glass* shader:

[image]